# Confusion matrix, threshold and ROC curve in statsmodel LogIt

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, statsmodels

The problem: I have a binary classifier and I want to fit a Logistic regression to my data using statsmodel. And I want some metrics, like the roc curve and to plot a confusion matrix. But I observed some discrepancy which seems strange between the roc curve and the confusion matrix. This is the very first time I am using statsmodel and since the [Documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.html), [and this one also](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Logit.predict.html), is not very informative, I do not know what to do...

Well, I have a dataset in pandas which I split into `X_variables` and the `y_variable`. More precisely, the X entry is a matrix `model_matrix` and the binary response is the column `with_payment` from my dataframe `df`. The code:

```
log_reg = sm.Logit(df['with_payment', model_matrix).fit()

##Adding predictions:
model_matrix['pred'] = log_reg.predict(model_matrix)
```

returns what exactly?

I was certain that the object `log_reg` which is the model fitted in the dataframe would keep some information like the best threshold so it can be able to classify data. But it does not seem to be the case since the `predict` method is returning 0 for everything. I mean, the result is something like `10^-2` when the data is 1 and `10^-5` when the data is 0.

I plotted a roc curve:

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(df['with_payment'], model_matrix['pred'])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
print("Area under the ROC curve : %f" % roc_auc)
```

[image]

But the confusion matrix is...:

```
model_matrix['with_payment'] = df['with_payment']

prediction= np.round(model_matrix['pred'])
cm = confusion_matrix(model_matrix['with_payment'], prediction)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix= cm)
disp.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is it right? Does it make sense that the ROC curve is what it is and the confusion matrix is one of a model that guess everything as label= 0? I mean, my ROC curve is not a ROC for a model that guess label=0 for everything. Why the discrepance? I believe I am misusing statsmodel, but I do not know why and where.

Do I need to input the threshold by hand in some way? Why statsmodel is giving 0 as prediction to all data? Am I wrong in thinking that the `predict` method would use the an optimized threshold, and if it is not so, where should I put the threshold?

Libraries used, in case it is needed to be specified:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

Comment: `predict` in Logit returns predicted probabilities. Converting this to a decision and choosing a threshold is up to the user and depends on the cost of making different types of errors in the decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think it's because your data is imbalanced. You have a label=1 to label=0 ratio of 0.83%. You can try the `LogisticRegression` object from the [`sklearn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) package. There you have the option to specify `class_weight='balanced'`. I am not sure if `statsmodels` also supports this. Alternatively, you could resample you data to fix the imbalance problem. For that, I highly recommend using the package [`ìmblearn`](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/user_guide.html), which is an extension of scitkit-learn and straight-forward to implement.